# How to run Eclipse Maven builds with command-line arguments

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am converting projects to Maven using Eclipse. A little background:

We are behind a firewall that does not allow access to the Maven central repo; instead, we have a corporate mirror repository that requires a keystore file to connect to. The file is provided, and we are able to build successfully using maven in the command line with `mvn clean compile package`, using the argument `--Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore` to point to the file.

This works fine outside of eclipse, but the integrated Maven plugin fails to build because it cannot connect to the repository without the keystore, so all of our code is littered with import/package errors, which makes it extremely tedious to get anything done.

I need to be able to configure Eclipse to have this command line argument whenever I run one of the internal Maven operations like `Run As -> Maven Install`. Using Run Configurations works, but it does not change the context menu Maven options, and does not clear up the import errors.

Eclipse 4.6.2 Java EE edition, Windows 7 x64

Comment: How about adding it to cacerts.

Comment: What is cacerts and how would I do that? This is a JKS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore...` to the `eclipse.ini` file associated with your Eclipse installation.